# Load data from SQL Server to datagridview using a thread

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to load data from a SQL Server database into a DataGridView using threading with delegates and later will try to add a loading or waiting form. But I can't make it work.

```vb
Dim t1 As Thread

Private Delegate Sub delegate_updatedgv()

Private Sub mainform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    t1 = New Thread(AddressOf load_dgv)
    t1.Start()
End Sub

Private Function load_dgv()
    Try
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            DBCon.Open()
        End If

        DBCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Jobs ", DBCon)
        DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim DBDT = New DataTable
        Dim DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd)
        Dim RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)
        assignit(DBDT)
        DBCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Try
End Function

Sub assignit(ByVal x As DataTable)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New delegate_updatedgv(AddressOf assignit))
    End If
    GridControl1.DataSource = x
End Sub
```

and its not working at all

Comment: "and its not working at all" - this is not a description of the problem. Add details, error you are getting and more...

Comment: The delegate and method signatures do not match

Comment: `"i solved the problem but need to add a waiting form to be shown before data completely gets loaded"`. So what was the problem? Please edit your question to clearly state it or this question has no value.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate

```vb
Private Delegate Sub delegate_updatedgv()
```

and your method

```vb
Sub assignit(ByVal x As DataTable)
```

don't have the same signature. Actually the compiler already tells you this in an error message...

You could just use `Action(Of DataTable)`. There is no need to create a new delegate.

You also needed to set the DataSource only when invoking on the UI thread. You can achieve that by using `Else`.

```vb
Sub assignit(ByVal x As DataTable)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then 
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of DataTable)(AddressOf assignit))
    Else
        GridControl1.DataSource = x
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can also declare the delegate properly. Either way

```vb
Private Delegate Sub delegate_updatedgv(x As DataTable)
```

Also, the method / function `Private Function load_dgv()` has no return type, and nothing is returned. So it is better suited as a sub.

```vb
Private Sub load_dgv()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

The compiler also warns you about this.

Pay attention to compiler error messages!

Comment: i changed sub assignit with your code and it still says addressof can not be converted to a delegate

Comment: @christymallony then `Me.Invoke(New Action(Of DataTable)(AddressOf assignit))`

Comment: @christymallony sorry I have some extension methods which allow for my original suggestion. I have updated it to use Action

Comment: i solved the problem but need to add a waiting form to be shown before data completely gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

While we are at, let's fix up the database code a bit. There is no need to check connection state when database objects are keep local to the method where they are used. This way you can ensure that they are closed and disposed with a `Using...End Using` block.

I have no idea why you are calling `.ExecuteNonQuery` on this command. You never use `RecordCount` so I don't see the point of that either. I just used one line to load the DataTable. The adapter seemed extraneous.

```
Private Sub load_dgv()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
        DBCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Jobs ", DBCon)
        DBCon.Open()
        dt.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    assignit(dt)
End Sub
```

I know this didn't answer your threading question but I hope it helped for data access.

Where is the bottleneck in this code? Is it just the retrieval of data or is it updating the UI? Maybe only the data access needs to run on a separate thread.

Comment: thanks , i receive an error of parameter count mismatch and i want to add a waiting form (loading ) while data are being loaded

Comment: That is an interesting error since there are no parameters. What line does the code error on?

Comment: i solved the problem but need to add a waiting form to be shown before data completely gets loaded