# Refresh datagridview after inserting records into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to update datagridview after inserting a new record.

The following button is located on a form and the datagridview is located on another form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using DBCon As New SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.4,1433;Database=example;User=test;Pwd=test;"),
    DBCmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Jobs (Zone,Equipement,Description) 
VALUES ( '" & TextEdit1.Text & "','" & TextEdit2.Text & "','" & TextEdit3.Text & "') ", DBCon)
            DBCon.Open()
            dt.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
            mainform.GridControl1.DataSource = dt

        End Using

        MsgBox.Show("Record Has been Added Successfully!!")
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgeBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: **PLEASE** *parametrise* your query first! [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: its working fine and row gets inserted  but i need to reload the datagridview form in order to see the new row

Comment: *"its working fine"* No, it's not, it's wide open to injection. It certainly won't be working "fine" when something enters `'); DROP TABLE Jobs;--` in `TextEdit3.Text`...

Comment: Please do not share your credentials to the others anywhere.

Comment: its not my real credentials , thanks for advice

Comment: If for some reason you think your code is safe from injection then consider what happens if somebody puts something like Henry's into the Equipment textbox. Your code will fail. Parameterizing your sql not only prevents sql injection it deals with all sorts of other challenges. Once you learn how it is easier than any of the bizarre string manipulation work arounds anyway. Just learn how.

Comment: @Sean Lange thanks , what about  refreshing datagridview ?

Comment: Is this a windows app or a web app? In the web world you have to call DataBind() to update the contents of a grid.

Comment: @Sean Lange this is a windows app, winform

Comment: Show the code that loads your DataGridView the first time. You really just have to re-execute that code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285369/load-data-from-sql-server-to-datagridview-using-a-thread?noredirect=1#comment106670135_60285369          This is the code i use to load data for the first time

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the below code. Request you to go through this [link](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/) to know how to parametrize your query with CRUD demo.

```
dt.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
mainform.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
mainform.GridControl1.Refresh()
```

Comment: @christymallony After the message, you need to select the update on the value of dt. Your datagridview load display data on the datagridview first time or not?

Comment: when i go to datagridview form i already see data when i open Insert form and add data  it doesnt refresh and cant see the new added row

Comment: @christymallony After inserting the records you need to re-assign the data source to the GridControl and then call the Refresh. Your code is missing only the refresh as you have in your question.

Comment: i tried that before i post here and thats why you see DialogResult = DialogResult.OK  also because i also refresh in the main form and it doesnt work